# How do I calculate 40% of a colour tint?

Tags: colors

I need to calculate the hex value for a few colours which should be 40% tint of the given colours.
For example I'm given this colour: #46A3E0
How can I calculate 40% of its tint?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you consider its “tint” to be? When you attempted to solve this problem yourself, where did you get stuck?

Comment: You can you ```rbga()```, may be.

Comment: It's not about CSS. I just need to find out how to calculate the hex value of a colour, which is only 40% of the original colour.

Comment: Convert to HSV/HSL, reduce the `v` of HSV or `l` of HSL to 40%, and (if required for your output) convert back to RGB https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/why-do-we-use-the-hsv-colour-space-so-often-in-vision-and-image-processing (HSL or HSV choice depends on your definition of tint)

Answer (score 0):

in css add `filter: brightness(40%)` for a darker tint for example

also check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function for more useful "filters" to use in CSS for other types of tints

Comment: It's not about CSS. I just need to find out how to calculate the hex value of a colour, which is only 40% of the original colour.

Comment: is this even a programming question? either way, try using this website https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel

Comment: Yes, because I need the hex value to use it for styling app elements.

Comment: @user1941537 then don't tag the question with [css]

Comment: Thanks guys. I found this site, which I think can help me:
https://www.color-hex.com/color/46a3e0